# Easiest scripting method to merge two text files - Ruby, Python, JavaScript, Java?

Tags: java, javascript, python, ruby, scripting

I have two text files, one containing HTML and the other containing URL slugs:

**FILE 1 (HTML):**

```
<li><a href="/article/"><button class="showarticle"/><span class="author">Thomas Friedman</span> - <span class="title">The World Is Flat</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/article/"><button class="showarticle"/><span class="author">Michael Dagleish</span> - <span class="title">Scotland In Wartime</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/article/"><button class="showarticle"/><span class="author">Dr. Raymond Kinsella</span> - <span class="title">Progress In Cancer Treatments</span></a></li>
...
```

**FILE 2 (URL SLUGS):**

```
thomas-friedman-the-world-is-flat
michael-dagleish-scotland-in-wartime
dr-raymond-kinsella-progress-in-cancer-treatments
...
```

I need to merge them so that the slugs in FILE 2 are inserted into the HTML in FILE 1 like this:

**OUTPUT:**

```
<li><a href="/article/thomas-friedman-the-world-is-flat"><button class="showarticle"/><span class="author">Thomas Friedman</span> - <span class="title">The World Is Flat</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/article/michael-dagleish-scotland-in-wartime"><button class="showarticle"/><span class="author">Michael Dagleish</span> - <span class="title">Scotland In Wartime</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/article/dr-raymond-kinsella-progress-in-cancer-treatments"><button class="showarticle"/><span class="author">Dr. Raymond Kinsella</span> - <span class="title">Progress In Cancer Treatments</span></a></li>
```

What's the best approach and which language would be most appropriate to accomplish this task with a minimum of complexity?

Comment: I'd do it in perl, but only because I have 10+ years of experience in perl.

Comment: Are the files guaranteed to be in the same order?

Comment: I'd do it in perl, but only because perl would be really good for this problem. I have 10+ minutes of experience in perl.

Comment: @katrielalex: Good question. Yes, the files match up, line for line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need zip-function, which is available in most languages. It's purpose is parallel processing of two or more arrays.
In Ruby it will be something like this:

```
f1 = File.readlines('file1.txt')
f2 = File.readlines('file2.txt')

File.open('file3.txt','w') do |output_file|

    f1.zip(f2) do |a,b|
        output_file.puts a.sub('/article/','/article/'+b)
    end

end
```

For zipping more, than two arrays you can do `f1.zip(f2,f3,...) do |a,b,c,...|`

Comment: @Sven Marnach, sure, I forgot to say it when posted ) I've updated answer.

Comment: You can do f1.zip(f2,f3,...) in ruby

Answer (score 2):

This will be easy in any language. Here it is in pseudo-Python; I've omitted the `lxml` bits because I don't have access to them and I can't quite remember the syntax. They're not difficult, though.

```
with open(...) as htmls, open(...) as slugs, open(...) as output:
    for html, slug in zip(htmls, slugs):
        root = lxml.etree.fromstring(html)
        # do some fiddling with lxml to get the name

        slug = slug.split("-")[(len(name.split()):]
        # add in the extra child in lxml

        output.write(root.tostring())
```

Interesting features:

- This doesn't read in the entire file at once; it does it chunk by chunk (well, line-by-line but Python will buffer it). Useful if the files are huge, but probably irrelevant.
- `lxml` may be overkill, depending on how rigid the format of the html strings is. If they're guaranteed to be the same and all well-formed, it might be easier for you to use simple string operations. On the other hand, `lxml` is pretty fast and offers a lot more flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby one liner:

```
File.open("joined.txt","w") { |f| f.puts ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt'].map{ |s| IO.read(s) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use the language of the listed ones that you are most familiar with.  Even if it doesn't produce the neatest solution, you'll get the job done with the least (mental) effort.

If you know none of them, then Perl is a good option because this is the kind of thing it was designed to do.  (I'm assuming that you understand regular expressions ...)  And by the look of some of the other answers, Python is a good option too.

Comment: No, I don't know regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Python is great language
Just have a look at these six lines of python 
they can merge any big text file, just now i have merged 2 text file of 10 GB each.

```
 o = open("E:/temp/3.txt","wb") #open for write
 for line in open("E:/temp/1.txt","rb"):
     o.write(line)
 for line in open("E:/temp/2.txt","rb"):
     o.write(line)
 o.close()
```

Answer (score -2):

PHP is the easiest!

```
$firstFile = file('file1.txt');
$secodFile = file('file2.txt');

$findKey='/article/';
$output='';

if (count($firstFile)==count($secodFile)) 
                    or die('record counts dont match');

for($i=0;$i<count($firstFile);$i++)
{
    $output.=str_replace($findKey,$findKey.trim($secodFile[$i]),$firstFile[$i]);
}

file_put_contents('output.txt',$output);
```

Comment: Die! die! die! Excellent exception handling )

Comment: Have you tested this code? It looks rather messy and the use of `die` is so unnecessary. http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php explains why die() is not recommended.

Comment: This code is far from the easiest one!