# How to merge the two csv files into one csv when we declared in two different module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> I have defined this csv files into two modules to get the data while
>   exporting, now i need these data's in a sngle sheet sheet ca any one
>   suggest me how merge this code into single CSV, since  for me it is
>   throwing an error, and i have defind 2 controllers also saparately.

```
def self.to_csv
 attributes = %w{ Employee-Code Employee-Name Entity Department-Code Designation-Code Date-Of-Joining Primary-Phone Secondary-Phone Emergency-Phone Primary-Email Secondary-Email Status} 
        CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
        csv << attributes
        Employee.all.each do |employee|
                csv << [employee.emp_code,employee.emp_name,employee.entity.entity_code,employee.department.depart_code,employee.designation.designation_code,employee.date_of_joining,employee.primary_phone,employee.secondary_phone,employee.emergency_phone,employee.primary_email,employee.secondary_email,employee.status]
                csv.sort_by { |employee| employee['emp_code']}
            end
        end
end
```

> this is one  employee module which is stored data in employee_table im
>   feteching data from this table only

```
def self.to_csv
attributes = %w{ Employee-code Date-Of-Birth Sex Marital-Status Anniversary-Date  Permanent-Addr Communication-Addr State City Years-Of-Experience Height Weight Bank-Name Account-Number IFSC-Code Blood-Group} 
        CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
            csv << attributes
            PersonalInfo.all.each do |personalinfo|     
                csv << [personalinfo.employee.emp_code,personalinfo.date_of_birth,personalinfo.sex,personalinfo.marital_status,personalinfo.anniversary_date,personalinfo.permanent_addr,personalinfo.commn_addr,personalinfo.years_of_experience,personalinfo.height,personalinfo.weight,personalinfo.acc_no,personalinfo.ifsc_code,personalinfo.blood_group]
            end
        end
end
```

> this is another module which data is stored personal table im fetching
>   from here only now i want join these two csv files into single csv... 
>   can any one suggest me how to do, for these two module two action
>   controllers i have written and routing also based on that.... how to
>   merge these two file

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to achieve, but if you want to just merge the two files, I would do something like proposed in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475855/easiest-scripting-method-to-merge-two-text-files-ruby-python-javascript-jav).

EDIT: here is the code

```
f1 = File.read('file1.csv')
f2 = File.read('file2.csv')

File.write('file3.csv', f1 + f2)
```

Comment: see i want to export the data into CSV format,  according to my code it is working but im getting two separate sheets, now i need both in single sheets

Comment: So the link above is exactly what you want: merging the two CSV files together into one CSV file.

Comment: im sorry to say i have given that also, but still im getting in two saparate sheets