# combine large files together

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

I have several files on my hard drive that need to be put back together as one file and written back to the hard drive. the files total over 2GB so it is producing the following error while i work with them: "OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory." i think my code is simply taking too much ram. Anyone have any other ideas?

```
   i=0;bt=new byte[0];
while(i>-1){
   if(i<10){txt="0"+i;}else{txt=""+i;}
   txt=dir+"/"+dstring+"/"+"part"+txt+".tdd";
   if(File.Exists(txt)){
         bt=bt+File.ReadAllBytes(txt);// <--error is here
         i++;}
         else{i=-1;}
 }
 print("saving"+bt.Length);
 File.WriteAllBytes(dir+"/"+dstring+"/"+dstring+".mp4",bt);
```

Comment: it's javascript written for unity3d.

Comment: Unity is a game engine. Not a file merge engine... How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475855/easiest-scripting-method-to-merge-two-text-files-ruby-python-javascript-jav

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to keep all files in the RAM at once. Since the total size of the files is huge (as you said in your question), you should do this instead:

- Step 1) Create an empty file at the desired location.
- Step 2) Write the contents of each file to the file created in Step 1 **ONE BY ONE**.

There's no way to over-emphasize the fact that you **MUST** write the files one by one instead of all at once.

Comment: Note to self: [Markdown doesn't work in edit summaries.](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39057148/2)

Answer (score 0):

Darukayan is correct. Someone on another forum gave me a code example to fix my problem. Here is what I ended up using:

```
 function combine (){

 //----finds an indefinate amount of files named part00.ttd, part01.tdd,part03.tdd
 //----in a folder and combines them into one file

      var outStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(dir+"/"+dstring+"/"+dstring+".mp4");

       i=0; 
       while(i>-1){

       if(i<10){txt="0"+i;}else{txt=""+i;}

       txt=dir+"/"+dstring+"/"+"part"+txt+".tdd";

       if(File.Exists(txt)){

          var inStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(txt);    
          var fileinfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(txt);
          var countread:int = fileinfo.Length;

          var filebytes:byte[]=new byte[countread];

              inStream.Read(filebytes, 0, countread);
              outStream.Write(filebytes, 0, countread);
              inStream.Close();

          i++;}else{i=-1;}

        }

       outStream.Close();
}
```